# Can not stop music when back to first view controller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've build a second view controller for a radio app to send text's to the radiostation. So, when i press play on the first view controller it play's the stream and you can check what's playing now and coming up. I've made a button to the second view controller, the music is still playing, that's good! But i can't stop it in ControlCenter and when i go back to the first view controller the button is back to "Play" and not "Stop" in the app.

Seems like the first view controller is getting a "reset?" when you go to the second view controller. How can i fix this?

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNC7k.jpg

- Dennis

Answer (score 1):

You can also declare your audioPlayer in the appDelegate  :

```
// inside AppDelegate
var ap : AVAudioPlayer? = nil
```

then simply declare in your viewController :

```
var ap : AVAudioPlayer? {
    get {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        return appDelegate.ap
    }
    set {
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
        appDelegate.ap = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: This works for me. My issue: when a back from music player to prevues view controller, music will be stopped. Thanks. It's working now.